# To have no pagebreak before Bibliography 

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

The position of Bibliography section is defined by document class, report class is a new page, some articles class no has page break.

How change this witout change the class of the document? So i have a report class but how generate Bibliography without page break.

Comment: You can check the `report` source code, find the macro placing the bibliography, and use `\renewcommand` in your preamble to remove the call to `\pagebreak` or similar.

Comment: So you want your bibliography to show like a section instead of like a chapter?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, rigth

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Internally, `thebibliography` environment uses `\chapter*`; if you want the bibliography to behave like a section, you can patch the `\thebibliography` command to use `\section*` instead of `chapter*`. To do this, add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{a} Test A.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the `biblatex` package is used to produce the bibliography, one can use `\defbibheading` to define a heading using `\section*`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibheading{secbib}[\bibname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=secbib]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I there a way to do the same thing if I am using bibtex (not biblatex)?

Answer (score 25):

If you are using the `natbib` package, you may try the option `sectionbib`:

`\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}`

Comment: This is so much simpler than the top answer 

Comment: Solved a similar issue with the `bibentry` package

Comment: Works in conjunction with numbers, as: `\usepackage[numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}`

Comment: This works, but it affects the level of the bibliography in your TOC

Answer (score 17):

If the `biblatex` package is used to produce the bibliography, you can also use one of the predefined headings, i.e. `subbibliography`

For instance:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
```

You can refer to section *3.6.8 Bibliography Headings and Environments* in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: This works like a charm, n.b. the actual command is `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]`

Answer (score 3):

`bilatex` package is useful and very easy in such case. Suppose,

1. You want a section inside document as well as an un-numbered section entry in table of contents, then use

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,] % TOC has an entry 'References' as an un-numbered section
   ```
2. You just want a section inside document and no entry in table of contents, then use

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,] % No entry in TOC
   ```

An MWE, borrowed from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74298/) would be like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\lipsum[1]
\nocite{*}
% un-comment any one from the following as per your choice
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,] % No entry in TOC
%\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,] % TOC has an entry 'References' as an un-numbered section
\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed the definition of `secbib` that remained in the copy of Gonzalo's MWE, it was not used here and would probably only confuse people.

Comment: FWIW I think this use of `subbibliography` or `subbibintoc` (or `subbibnumbered`) is generally slightly nicer than a new heading definition such as `secbib` in simple cases. But in more complicated case a new definition might be inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, when using the `llncs` class together with the `natbib` package, one gets a bibliography on a separate page, listing reference indexed as `[1]`, `[2]`... instead of `1.`, `2.`... as expected by LNCS.

To avoid that problem, I use:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
% Hack natbib so it matches the LNCS style: reference list in a
% section with small font and no square brackets.
\renewcommand\bibsection
  {\section*{\refname}\small\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{##1.}}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use koma-script, you can select this in the options. The option *leveldown* changes the bibliography from a chapter to a section in the class scrbook. I borrow the nice example from Gonzalo Medina above:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{9} 
\bibitem{a} Test A.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]