# Show complete reference in the output

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm using a bib file to insert all my references. The bibliography is generated ok in the output. However, some references are shown between two pages (it means, the reference starts at the end of one page and it finishes at the beggining of the next). How can I do to make somekind of \newpage inside the bib file? I would like to show the entire reference information within the same page (not divided between two pages).

Raúl

Comment: Welcome! See also [To have no pagebreak before Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74296/to-have-no-pagebreak-before-bibliography).

Comment: use `\newpage` before `\bibliography{...}` or `\begin{thebibliography}{..}`

Comment: I think that the question is asking how to avoid a page break in the *middle* of *one* reference.

Comment: That's correct @Andrew. Do you know how?

Comment: Great!  This works for me. \interlinepenalty=10000 before 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{exemple_bibtex}