Print multiple bibliographies on the same page
I would like to have two bibliographies on the same page. The code is as follows:
\documentclass[11pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}

\title{Multiple Bibliographies with biblatex: categories}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs-nokeywords.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{paper1} and \cite{paper2} and \cite{paper3} and \cite{paper4} were published later.

\printbibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}

It turns out that there's a page break between two bibliographies. How can I solve this problem?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74296/114006

The bibliographies appear on different pages because they are defined as chapters in the class scrbook. You can use the class option bibliography=leveldown to remove the page break between them.
\begin{filecontents*}{refs-nokeywords.bib} % https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=https://assets.ctfassets.net/nrgyaltdicpt/3Bt5Tf9eSCtcXQrGshjQJT/7c64c3820a4adc4e20468aee752dc1e9/biblatex-keywords.zip
@article{paper1,
    title = {WordNet: a lexical database for English},
    year = {1995},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Miller, George A.},
    doi = {10.1145/219717.219748},
    number = {11},
    month = {11},
    pages = {39--41},
    volume = {38},
    publisher = {ACM}
}

@article{paper2,
    title = {Real-time computer vision with OpenCV},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Pulli, Kari and Baksheev, Anatoly and Kornyakov, Kirill and Eruhimov, Victor},
    doi = {10.1145/2184319.2184337},
    number = {6},
    month = {6},
    pages = {61},
    volume = {55},
    publisher = {ACM}
}
    
@inproceedings{paper3,
    title = {Face recognition using eigenfaces},
    year = {1991},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of 1991 IEEE Computer Society Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition},
    author = {Turk, M.A. and Pentland, A.P.},
    doi = {10.1109/CVPR.1991.139758},
    pages = {586--591},
    publisher = {IEEE Comput. Sco. Press},
    keywords={math}
}

@article{paper4,
  title={High energy colliders as black hole factories: The end of short distance physics},
  author={Giddings, Steven B and Thomas, Scott},
  journal={Physical Review D},
  volume={65},
  number={5},
  pages={056010},
  year={2002},
  keywords={phys}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt, twoside=false, bibliography=leveldown]{scrbook}

\title{Multiple Bibliographies with biblatex: categories}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs-nokeywords.bib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{paper1} and \cite{paper2} and \cite{paper3} and \cite{paper4} were published later.

\printbibliography
\printbibliography
\end{document}

If you don't prefer the class option bibliography=leveldown, you can go with a different method - setting the \printbibliography command option heading=subbibliography. But it would change the title of the bibliography to References. You can get back the original title with the option title=Bibliopgraphy.
\documentclass[11pt, twoside=false]{scrbook}

\title{Multiple Bibliographies with biblatex: categories}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{refs-nokeywords.bib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{paper1} and \cite{paper2} and \cite{paper3} and \cite{paper4} were published later.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=Bibliopgraphy]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, title=Bibliopgraphy]

\end{document}


\defbibheading{bibheading}{
  \section*{#1}
}

Will turn the reference heading into first level head and new page problem will fix
